How can I find the dependencies for chromdriver of google-chrome-stable on ubuntu linux
I am using selenium chromedriver and for that I need to install the Chrome dependencies (in my dockerfile) for linux (ubuntu). I tried searching but I cannot find a definitive list - just a lot of examples where people install something like:
RUN yum install -y libX11 libXcomposite libXcursor libXdamage libXext libXi libXtst cups-libs libXScrnSaver libXrandr alsa-lib pango atk at-spi2-atk gtk3

But where does that come from? And how can I check if  there are no new dependencies?

That package is available in your yum repo, to check your repo run yum repolist, then check the package from the listed repo list. For update you can run yum update though you need to know the difference between update and upgrade. See this yum cheat code

Hi @gopelkujo my issue is that I am on Debian but the image I am using is from CentOs (or similar), specifically 'amazoncorretto:17.0.11-al2'. Do you know how I could get the dependencies?

oh i see that's why im feeling weird that debian based linux using yum as package manager that usually used by red hat linux distro (such as fedora, centos, etc)

There's a documentation for installing amazoncorretto for debian based linux check this official doc. And if you need to install another package that not debian based or something else, you can search on google by keyword [package-name] for [linux-distro] example amazoncorretto for debian`. Don't worry, in linux everything is possible:)

Why do you run yum install on Ubuntu?

I needed it due to my Docker container being CentOs but my local development environment being on Linux.

I was able to get it in the following way:
Step 0:
Add 'wget' to the yum install list of where you define 'RUN yum install -y' in the Dockerfile

Bring up the container

SSh into it:
docker exec -it the_name /bin/bash


Step 3
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm (or downlaod the .rmp of what you need)
Step 4
run the following to get the dependencies
rpm -qp google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm --requires
